# How to write function decorator in c# like python

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I have worked on python for a while and returned to c# for a project. So I used to python language and that forces me think like a python programmer and i like this!

The question i want to ask how can i create a method that called after its decarator ?

Python decorator syntax:

```
def p_decorate(func):
   def func_wrapper(name):
       return "<p>{0}</p>".format(func(name))
   return func_wrapper

@p_decorate
def get_text(name):
   return "lorem ipsum, {0} dolor sit amet".format(name)
```

I have googled but found only .Net [Attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute(v=vs.110).aspx) And it couldn't helped me.

Sample code but i want to write my own AuthorizationAttribute class.

```
public class RestrictAccessToAssignedManagers : AuthorizationAttribute
{
    protected override AuthorizationResult IsAuthorized(System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal principal, AuthorizationContext authorizationContext)
    {
        EmployeePayHistory eph = (EmployeePayHistory)authorizationContext.Instance;
        Employee selectedEmployee;
        Employee authenticatedUser;

        using (AdventureWorksEntities context = new AdventureWorksEntities())
        {
            selectedEmployee = context.Employees.SingleOrDefault(e => e.EmployeeID == eph.EmployeeID);
            authenticatedUser = context.Employees.SingleOrDefault(e => e.LoginID == principal.Identity.Name);
        }

        if (selectedEmployee.ManagerID == authenticatedUser.EmployeeID)
        {
            return AuthorizationResult.Allowed;
        }
        else
        {
            return new AuthorizationResult("Only the authenticated manager for the employee can add a new record.");
        }
    }
}

[RestrictAccessToAssignedManagers]
public void InsertEmployeePayHistory(EmployeePayHistory employeePayHistory)
{
    if ((employeePayHistory.EntityState != EntityState.Detached))
    {
        this.ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(employeePayHistory, EntityState.Added);
    }
    else
    {
        this.ObjectContext.EmployeePayHistories.AddObject(employeePayHistory);
    }
}
```

Sample code from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707357(v=vs.91).aspx)

Comment: *I just write below code to explain what i want to do*: I think you'll need to be more explicit about you need to do.  I can't tell just from your sample code. And what's more, there is no symmetry between the sample .NET code and the Python code, so that makes it more confusing.  Maybe it's just me.

Comment: Sorry i am gone give more information

Comment: Is it that `p_decorate`, when applied to any method, intercepts any calls to that method, gets to execute its own code and can, at the time of its choosing, cause the method it's decorating to be executed? If so, there's no precisely analogous functionality directly available in C#, but something similar is doable with Aspect Oriented Programming. There are some frameworks such as PostSharp that let you do this.

Comment: What you've described with you example c# (Customer MVC authorize attribute) code is not done with decorators in ASP.NET - There are many online resources on how to achieve that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Often that is used in Aspect Oriented Programming, two popular libraries to do it are [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/) and [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody).

Here is a example with PostSharp of your original python example.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using PostSharp.Aspects;
using PostSharp.Extensibility;

namespace SandboxConsole
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(GetText("Test"));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        [Decorate]
        public static string GetText(string name)
        {
            return String.Format("lorem ipsum, {0} dolor sit amet", name);
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class DecorateAttribute : MethodInterceptionAspect
    {
        public override bool CompileTimeValidate(MethodBase method)
        {
            if (!((MethodInfo)method).ReturnType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(string)))
            {
                Message.Write(SeverityType.Error, "CUSTOM01", "Can not apply [Decorate] to method {0} because it does not retun a type that is assignable from string.", method);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
        {
            args.Proceed();
            args.ReturnValue = String.Format("<p>{0}</p>", args.ReturnValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the nuget package: [CompileTimeWeaver.Fody](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CompileTimeWeaver.Fody/)